# Break line on asp:label text using word-break on only long words?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have an asp:label that must fit in it's parent container

Problem is sometimes the text is one continuous sequence of characters with no white space.

I am looking for CSS behavior to break the word when the word is too long, but not break small sized words that can be shifted to the line below it.

This is what I originally had:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTextComments" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

This yields:

```
some normal text that 
breaks onto a new line
```

But this happens with a long word:

```
someverylongtextwithoutanywhitespaceatalldoesnotcausealinebreaktohappen
```

This runs off the web page.

I've used this CSS style solution:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTextComments" runat="server" Style="word-wrap: normal; word-break: break-all;" ></asp:Label>
```

This correctly breaks the long word:

```
someverylongtextwithoutanywh
itespaceatalldoesnotcauseali
nebreaktohappen
```

But this breaks small words that I wish to be moved to the next line:

```
some normal text tha 
t breaks onto a new line
```

Comment: Did you try `word-wrap: break-word;`?

Comment: @itsme86 that solved it

Comment: Great! I added it as an answer so others can find it if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```